# jquery cycle gallery populated by php

Tags: php, jquery, gallery, cycle

I have a simple jquery cycle gallery populated by PHP.  I would like to add an
"onclick" event corresponding to each image, revealing a higher resolution jpeg.
I would like to just put some inline javascript like so:

```
print('<div class="bigimg"><img onclick="javascrpt:load wrapper2 with (\''.$lrg_images.$file.'\')" src="' .  $cycle_images . $file . '" class="change" align="right"></div>'."\r\n");
```

...so each enlarged image is bound to it's cycle gallery counterpart.
Here is the meat of what I have so far.

```
 //directory containing large images
$lrg_images = './images/images_lrg/';
//directory containing medium images
$cycle_images = './images/images_med/';

function getPictures() {
    while ( $count < $per_page && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
        if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {
            print('<div class="bigimg"><img src="' .  $cycle_images . $file . '" class="change" align="right"></div>'."\r\n");
        }
    }
<!-- container for cycle gallery -->
<div id="feature_gallery"><?php getPictures(); ?></div>

<!-- container for enlarged image -->
<div id="wrapper2"></div>
```

Thanks and let me know if you need anything clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) plugin will be helpful to you.

You can have it bind to your elements so that when they are clicked, it opens.  There are examples of this on [the homepage](http://defunkt.io/facebox/).

Comment: My apologies for the delay, just checked it out. It took about five seconds to get setup and is a perfect solution really.  I was searching along the lines of 'modal' etc. and didn't pick up on this gem. Thanks so much.